# ggplot2 don't show me any plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this code (below) in order to build a density plot but while not giving any error as output, R studio does not display any graph in the section Plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame (x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
dat <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Age, color=Species)) + 
    geom_density(stat = "density") + 
    expand_limits(x=c (-1,10), y=c (1,15)) + 
    theme (panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), by = 0.5),1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = 0.5),1))
```

Comment: you need to print the object. Just running `dat` should do it

Comment: I did it but still dosen't works. No plot appear

Comment: your example data.frame has x and y, but the code has variables Age and Species which makes it impossible to run your code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame (x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
dat <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, color=y)) + 
  geom_density(stat = "density") + 
  expand_limits(x=c (-1,10), y=c (1,15)) + 
  theme (panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), by = 0.5),1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = 0.5),1))

plot(dat)
```

and the resulting plot:

[image]